# Index on Select Insert?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use a SELECT INSERT for my project; however, one of the columns that needs filled with the insert corresponds to it's position in the INSERT. I've tried using a subquery (as seen below) and just using the table name in the FROM clause of the SELECT -- neither seems to work.

The output I get is always "10001" instead of what I expect (i.e. "10001", "10002", "10003", etc.)

Any help?

```
INSERT INTO table
 (
  Key2
 )
SELECT 
 (SELECT IF(CAST(MAX(t.Key2) as UNSIGNED) IS NULL, "10001", CAST(MAX(t.Key2) as UNSIGNED)+1) FROM (select * from table) t)
FROM table2
```

Comment: I believe the issue with your logic is that you're using an aggregate function (max()). This limits the values coming back to just 1 value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631096/mysql-incrementing-value

Answer (score 2):

If you want enumerated keys, then use variables:

```
INSERT INTO table (Key2)
    SELECT COALESCE(maxkey, 0) + (@rn := @rn + 1)
    FROM table2 CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(t.key) maxkey, @rn := 0 FROM table) x ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (KEY2)
SELECT A.KEY2 + B.MAX_VAL AS KEY2 FROM TABLE A
JOIN (SELECT MAX(KEY2) AS MAX_VAL FROM TABLE) B
ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: The problem is that it executes the SELECT before the inserts -- and it doesn't subsequently SELECT again in between inserts. 

So the value always appears to be NULL because that was the original value prior to attempting the insertion.

Comment: @JordanHarris afaik no sane RDBMS supports what I can only guess would be called recursive queries like that. I'm not sure about others, but MySQL won't even let you insert into the table from a trigger on the table.

Comment: An Insert-Select will always select before the insert. Can you provide an example starting dataset and what you intend on the final dataset looking like?

Comment: If @Uueerdo is correct, then I'm not sure how I'd do what I'm trying to do.

I start off with an empty table and I want the column of each record to be n + 1 greater than the last record inserted.

So the first record would be Key2 = "10001", the second would be Key2 = "10002", etc.

I am not sure how to do that outside of the method I've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: @JordanHarris if you want multiple rows, you'll need to execute multiple inserts, or use a select that returns multiple rows. The select of an insert-select will never include the rows it is inserting.

Comment: @JordanHarris Are you looking to have an auto_increment column for your key? You can use a Database Sequence / Trigger combination to achieve this. Some RDBMS systems have auto_increment built-in.

Comment: I would never hamstring myself like this problem seems to be doing to me. Unfortunately, I'm using someone else's data schema.

I need the column values to increment, but only on this INSERT. Not for every insert.